# Get 3G USB Modem's (Huawei K4201) USB/Serial Identifier on Mac

Tags: usb, modem

I have an Huawei K4201 USB modem and a Mac running Mavericks. My ultimate goal is to be able to control it via a Java app. To do this, I first must get it's port name when plugged in.

Using the command `ls /dev/tty*` I can see devices I have plugged in (eg /dev/tty.usbserial). Remove the device and they disappear from Terminal's output.

This isn't true however of my USB modem, which doesn't appear at all.

Why is this? With my current (limited) understanding of Java I need this `/dev/tty.usbserial` identifier before I can begin to try to control it.

Any help greatly appreciated.